# Javascript regular expression that allow only alphabet, space and - only

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regular expression that allow only alphabet, one space after word, and - only
it will not accept two word but single space after word allowed. Any ther special character are not allowed.
Example

```
John -> true
John(space) -> true
John-Doe -> true
John-Doe(space) -> true
(space)John -> false
John Doe -> false
```

I am trying using this [a-zA-Z-][a-zA-Z -]
But not working exactly.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to allow consecutive hyphens `--` in the pattern, you might write the pattern as:

```
^[A-Z][a-z]+ ?(?:-[A-Z][a-z]+ ?)?$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[A-Z][a-z]+ ?` Match a char A-Z and 1+ chars a-z followed by an optional space (or `[A-Za-z]+` if you want to allow mixed chars)
- `(?:-[A-Z][a-z]+ ?)?` Optionally match the same as the preceding pattern with a leading `-`
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JqwjkL/1)

---

If you want to allow all mixed chars with an optional space at the end:

```
^[A-Za-z-]+ ?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iBhtyc/1)